# MySQL Query interfaceerror

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, mysql-connector

I am getting below error while executine a SQL Query on MySQL 5.5.23 server.
i am using MySQl connector downloaded from MySql site

`mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

The same Query id working on Win 7 but not on Win XP

Anybody has any idea...?

I am using MySql connector 1.0.5 with Python 2.6 and PyQt.

Some times its working, some time i get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the release notes of MySQL Connector/Python 1.0.8, This is a driver bug. Which was addressed in Connector/Python 1.0.8.

```
Intermittent errors could occur on Windows systems: InterfaceError(errno=2013).
The cause was incorrect handling of sock.recv() library calls that returned less
data than was requested. (Bug #14829471, Bug #67303)
```

But 1.0.8 version uses some windows functions for network IP address conversion which is available only in Windows Vista and above, But not in Win XP.

This bug in MySql Connector/Python 1.0.8 was reported [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68065) and will be fixed in 1.0.9

Answer (score 0):

You suggest that you are executing your query successfully in one environment, but not another?

also, what language are you using?  Can you post your code? Is it java i guess?  It's rather difficult to answer your question with an only error message and no periferal details.

as a hunch (and a wild one at that)- did you successfully connect to your DB when executing your code on the same server as your db?   Does it fail only when your are executing your code on a server different than your db server?  if so, go into my.cnf and coment out the line:

```
bind-address=.....
```

then restart mysql

just a wild stab, but add more details to your question please